# Code Definition Window on VS 2019 and VS 2022 on working

Tags: visual-studio

Does any body has an idea why Code Definition Window does not work showing message "No definition selected".

I have to put PC into sleep mode several times until it starts working. Note the problem exists on:

- two PCs with very different hardware;
- on Windows 10 and 11;
- with different projects;
- VS2019 and VS2022.

I never had such problem with VS2015.

Thank you, Alex